# Does spending a skill point give you a d4 or d6?

Tags: character-creation, skills, savage-worlds

When a new character is made in Savage Worlds, they have 15 points to spend on skills. According to the rulebook:

> Each die type costs 1 point (starting at d4)

The point of confusion for me here is this: When I spend a skill point, do I have a d4 in that skill, or a d6? Does "starting at" mean that the skill starts there and skill points increase above that level, or does it mean that your first skill point starts you at d4?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first skill point gets you a d4. Each die size costs 1 point, and the first is a d4.

The reason it specifies this is because it works differently from attributes. For those you get a d4 for free to start — because everyone has each attribute inherently — and the first point spent on an attribute upgrades the default d4 to a d6. Meanwhile, nobody starts life trained in every skill, so skills start at d-nothing, and the first point upgrades that to a d4.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the rule for rolling against an untrained skill just to round this answer off

Comment: Perhaps "everyone doesn’t have every skill" should be replaced with "not everyone has every skill" because it is indeed possible for a character to have every skill.

Comment: @JoelHarmon Good point. How’s that edit?

Comment: You seem to have covered both comments well. Thanks!